# GreenMachine by Flevobike (recumbent) - Clicking Noise When Pedaling

Tags: recumbent, rohloff

[image]The clicking is most noticeable when in lower gears and just starting off on a ride.  After about 5 minutes it is still there but not as loud.

There are two chains, one from the pedals to the mid-mounted Rohloff hub, and a second one from the hub to the freewheel in the rear wheel. Everything is encased in rectangular aluminum that forms the frame.

It's hard to tell where the noise is coming from but sounds like somewhere between the pedals and the hub.  Any ideas?

---

[image: Stock photo of Green Machine]

Comment: Before we dive into it, the tag _clicking_ gives a good collection of similar problems - we've had it all from loose crank bolts over classic bottom bracket issues to ungreased hubs and noise from freehub splines - see https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clicking

Comment: I can not help but I have asked on a Dutch recumbent riders forum, https://ligfietsers.nl/thread-1946-post-36800.html#pid36800 I will post reactions from there to here if they seem relevant.

Comment: @greenMachine When you get time, please do add some more photos of your progress and discoveries.  I'm fascinated how this has a rolhoff hub but not in the wheel.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments, photo, reposting, and links to discussions of similar clicking noise problems!  I will spend the next several days researching this information and performing some of the suggested diagnostics.

Comment: @Criggie, on page 7 of the exploded view, see link in my answer, you see the Rohloff with the chain towards the rear wheel, on page 3 is the chain towards the bracket. The pages in between are more pics.

Comment: It sounds like you might be referring to the spring-loaded chain tensioners, which might possibly be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Nice bent!

I'm unfamiliar with the stickbike design internally - are you able to unship the rear chain, and try pedalling just the front chain?  Of course you won't move, but if the clicking is evident you've eliminated the rear half.   If it DOESN'T click then that really proves nothing, because this test is under no-load.

Check the mileage on your chains and on the teeth too - it could be the chain has worn and now has more slack.  On a `bent that can add some significant droop to the longer runs, which could produce noise touching the inside of the frame ?

Try riding and coasting on a quiet smooth road; does the clicking stop while coasting?

Try backpedalling - does the clicking reappear?

Ask another rider to help with diagnosis - ride that same quiet road and see if they can get a "direction" on the click.   As the rider, sound can seem to come from one area but be from somewhere else.

I see in some photos that the bike's main "beam" can be angled at the hub.  If you change this angle does the clicking get more obvious or go away ?

Comment: I guess I will need to open up the frame, which I have been putting off for a while.  Besides, I just finished a cross-country ride on this bike and started with at least 10,000 miles, so it's probably time to change the chains anyway. Because they are totally enclosed and don't have to change sprockets, they have had a relatively easy life.

Comment: 10,000 miles is for a fully enclosed chain a good but not exceptional use. Please report back on the condition of the chain.

Comment: Thanks for helping me resolve this chain-clicking noise WITHOUT taking the bike apart to remove the chains.

The clicking noise happens regardless of the gear the Rohloff is in
It stops when I am not pedaling or pedaling backward
It quiets down a little when the bike warms up
The chains are well lubricated with silicone grease and ride in plastic tubes inside the frame.
I have posted a video featuring the noise and a drive chain PDF showing the components here:
https://gatewayboathouse-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/rick_horan_me/EraYX4Y9fv1FtZTTn45RN3MBCGBqwpMgAwyGBdY9pipJGQ?e=z3RQzp

Comment: >>> See/hear the video/audio file by clicking on the link above.  What does it sound like to you??

Answer (score 2):

In this [pdf download (parts names in Dutch)](https://paste.c-net.org/MajorlyAccosted) you find the bike 'exploded'.
It was suggested that the chain tensioner or a chain guide are likely to be the problem.

It is on page 12, says the person who suggested it.

Some more suggestions:

- Take of the chain cover so you can hear the tics louder if coming from the chain.
- If you suspect the pedals, taking them off and replacing them with a good amount of grease may help.
- A bolt or screw which has worked loose can get you a click, so tightening all you can find may help.

Comment: Thanks for the PDF file!  I gotta get inside the frame and poke around as it's definitely not the pedals.  I will order a pair of new chains and then see if anything else needs replacing or adjusting while I am in there and report back.